# Linux write() crashes application if file descriptor is closed

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, crash, file-descriptor

In my C++ application one thread uses the poll() function to be notified when a file descriptor is opened, data is available to read and the fd is closed. When data is available, it is read and delivered to other threads for processing and reply. In fact, on the other side the client waits on the open socket for a synchronous reply.
I make the best effort to notify the other threads when one fd is no more available, but without synchronizing (for now) the file descriptor set across all threads.
The problem is that this piece of code:

```
while(bytes < len && d->ok) {
        w = write(fd, buf + bytes, len - bytes);
        d->ok = (w >= 0);
        if(d->ok)
            bytes += w;
    }
```

crashes the entire application as soon as fd is closed.

Expected behaviour: write returns negative but no crash.
I've read on some thread that SIGPIPE is sent, and that's why the application crashes, but I find it's not documented explicitly in

man write

Options that come to my mind:

- synchronize the file descriptor set so that as soon as poll() notifies a fd is closed no other threads use it anymore
- use send() instead of write.

But, I guess, if fd is closed by the other end when I'm in the write() while cycle, I would get a crash instead of a simple negative result from write()

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I/O functions may lead to SIGPIPE, the faster the data is written, the more likely. The unfortunate effect being that your application just crashes without a chance for you to handle the error, which indeed can be very confusing. To solve this you just need to set the signal handler for SIGPIPE to SIG_IGN - then write() will instead return -1 with errno=EPIPE (Broken pipe) and you can close your side descriptor and clean up properly.

Answer (score 1):

You will never get your code to work reliably if a file descriptor can be closed in one thread while another thread is, or might be, using it. You *must* use some form of synchronization.

As just one example of what can go wrong, consider this:

1. Thread A closes file descriptor 10 just as thread B was about to `write` to it.
2. Before thread B can write, thread C opens and connects a new socket, it just happens tog et descriptor 10.
3. Thread B finally gets to execute, writing to file descriptor 10, but now that's the new connection that thread B opened.

Oops, you just wrote information to the wrong endpoint. I hope it wasn't security sensitive.

You must ensure that it is impossible for one thread to release a resource while another thread is or might be using it because if you don't, you will *always* have a possible race condition where one thread releases the resource *right* *before* another thread attempts to access it. And that's potentially disastrous.